# how to kill a program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to kill a program in python 3 when the user says 'no' to start a maths quiz, : here is the code I'm using

```
import sys

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")
    if new_item == "Yes" or "yes":
        break
    elif new_item == "no":
        sys.exit()
```

that doesn't work any pointers?

Comment: what is your question actually?

Comment: what you trying to do here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if new_item == "Yes" or "yes":
```

You need to use either:

```
if new_item in ["Yes", "yes"]:
```

or:

```
if new_item == "Yes" or new_item == "yes"
```

Your original code is parsed as:

```
if (new_item == "Yes") or "yes":
```

and this always evaluates to `True` since `"yes"` is a true value.

Answer (score 1):

```
if new_item == "Yes" or "yes":
```

This conditional is always `True`. It may be stated as:

```
(new_item == "Yes") or ("yes")
```

Non-empty string `'yes'` is always evaluated to `True`.

Change conditional to:

```
if new_item in ['Yes', 'yes']:
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your if statement, it isn't evaluating properly. You need to use this code to fix your problem:

```
import sys

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")
    if new_item == "Yes" or new_item == "yes":
        break
    elif new_item == "no":
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
import sys

while True:
    new_item = input("> ")
    new_item = new_item.lower() 
    #everything you wrote in input will be lowercase, no more "or" problems
    if new_item.lower() == "yes":
        break
    elif new_item.lower() == "no":
        sys.exit()
```